# Is there a script I can use where enter a url and it grabs images?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing a site where an image needs to be grabbed on the page... e.g. I would present to the end-user a text input - they enter the url....and it finds the images on the page if they are over "x"px dimensions..for example..if they enter a url to an amazon product page  - ...it then grabs the product image.... and then saves on my server...

Does anyone know of an off-the-shelf script that can do this or an online tutorial? - Think of Facebook..when you enter the url...of somethign to share, it grabs the image...and text on that page.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't the script shopping channel. Need some help with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how familiar with python you are, but there is a good library for web scraping there, called scrapy

http://scrapy.org/

That's if you can use something else then javascript or jquery